# javah checks sources modification time since JDK 7

Tags: javah

I have this trivial source code. I build it with JDK 6. The build goes fine with JDK 6 and produces two build artifacts: ./Class_B.class and subdir/Class_A.class.

```
public class Class_B extends Class_A {} (File ./Class_B.java)
public class Class_A {}                 (File ./subdir/Class_A.java)
```

Applying javah from JDK 6 passes, but javah from JDK 7+ fails:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah -d out -classpath . Class_B
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah -d out -classpath . Class_B
Error: cannot access Class_A
  class file for Class_A not found
```

BUT! It fails only till the modification time of Class_B.class is newer than of Class_B.java.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aaa aaa 402 Jun  7 12:00 Class_B.class
-rwxr-xr-x 1 aaa aaa 139 Jun  7 11:56 Class_B.java
```

If I "touch" the .java then the new javah also passes!

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aaa aaa 402 Jun  7 12:00 Class_B.class
-rwxr-xr-x 1 aaa aaa 139 Jun  7 12:01 Class_B.java
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah -d out -classpath . Class_B
$ echo $?
$ 0
```

On my opinion it makes sense to fail if the source is newer (the binary was not rebuilt).
However it behaves vice-versa: it's OK if the source is newer and fails unless `-classpath .:subdir` is given if the source is older.

WHY??? Where is this change documented? I cannot find in javah documentation (for example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html) anything about this modification time check.

**UPDATE**: Explanation regarding possibility of using "javac -h":

1. `javah` in JDK6 works even without `-classpath .;./subdir`
2. `javah` in JDK7 conditionally works without `-classpath .;./subdir` (depending on the modification time)
3. `javac -h` works only with `-classpath .;./subdir`

I am just interested to know about the difference between "1" and "2".
"3" makes no sense, because it can't work without classpath at all.

Comment: Does the same issue happen with more recent Java versions (with `javac -h`)?

Comment: It is not possible to check completely the same case with "javac -h". Let me explain please. "javac -h" fails if the "subdir" is not in `-classpath` - YES. The main point is that even without "subdir" in `-classpath` javah works always in JDK6 and _conditionally_ works (depending on the .java modification time) in JDK7,8. In distinct to javah "javac -h" always requires the full classpath to all sources, therefore it is impossible to test my case with "javac -h".

Comment: What happens with (a recent update version of) `javah` with java 8?